# bind entry and button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

i have a program which start by asking user his code so user will type code in Entry and click button  or click enter in keyboard i made two similar function with different inputs to deal with this

```
b1 = Button(root,text='login',command = Login_click)
b1.pack()
b1.bind('<Return>',Login_bind)
def Login_click(self):
    do some thing
def Login_bind(self,event):
    do something
```

and it works very fine but is there any way to make only one function deal with clicked and enter key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply define a function with `event=None` as a default value so that it is optional and then use the same function for both.

```
b1 = Button(root,text='login',command = Login_click_and_bind) 
b1.pack()
b1.bind('<Return>',Login_click_and_bind)
def Login_click_and_bind(self,event=None):
    do something
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you took the time to give an example.